# Laplace transform in complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I want this differential equations
$$
\partial_x^2 f - \frac{a}{a+c} f = g,
$$
where $g$ is a function, $a\in \mathbb{C}$ and $c>0$. Can I apply Laplace transform  considering the complex coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, why not?  Of course the result will involve complex numbers as well.

Comment: And what happen with the inverse ? is it possible also?

Comment: Are you asking whether complex-valued functions have inverse Laplace transforms?  The answer is yes.